# Jquery HTML5 select dropdown restyling conflict. Need multiple select dropdowns on same page

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

Greetings,

I am restyling the select element with HTML5 and jQuery. I can successfully create one dropdown with a .js file dedicated to the element, but I need help on populating the page with multiple instances of this element.

The select element can be summarized as this:

```
<form>
<select name="fancySelect" class="makeMeFancy">
<option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose Your Location</option>
<option value="1" data-html-text="United States">United States</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The js is more complex and seeks to hide the select element and replace it.
Briefly:

```
var select = $('select.makeMeFancy');
var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>',{
    width       : select.outerWidth(),
    className   : 'tzSelect',
    html        : '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
});

var dropDown = $('<ul>',{className:'dropDown'});
var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');
```

It then creates css styles for this element further down the script.

My question is how do I maintain this one javascript document for multiple select elements. Is it possible with one main variable and multiple select classnames i.e.

```
var select =$('select.makeMeFancy');
var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>',{
width   : select.outerWidth(),
className   : 'tzSelect','tzSelectb','tzSelectc'
html        : '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
```

HTML example is available at: [select restyling example](http://nutnics.com/som/selectx.html) updated: **SOLVED**

I have 3 elements inline, and as you can see it pulls the code into the very last select element and groups them altogether.

Sorry for the sloppy description, I think this should be everything.

The original dropdown was created by Turtorial Zine over at [TutorialZine "Making better select elements"](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/)

Comment: Solved, the plug in was available on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually have converted this to a plugin on their website. See [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/02/converting-jquery-code-plugin/). No need to reinvent the wheel.

**Edit**
According to the tutorial:

> You can use this plugin by simply
>   dropping the tzSelect folder
>   (available from the download button
>   above) into your project root, and
>   including jquery.tzSelect.css and
>   jquery.tzSelect.js in your HTML
>   documents.

*Example Code (From Tutorial)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select.makeMeFancy').tzSelect({
        render : function(option){
            return $('<li>',{
                html:   '<img src="'+option.data('icon')+'" /><span>'+
                        option.data('html-text')+'</span>'
            });
        },
        className : 'hasDetails'
    });

    // Calling the default version of the dropdown
    $('select.regularSelect').tzSelect();

});
```

Comment: Nice catch, I should've looked for their plug in. I will update my dropdowns with this and respond with the results

Answer (score 1):

First off, the Tutorial Zine code wasn't coded to support multiple elements.  The best solution would be to create a jQuery plugin that supported multiple elements, but that greatly broadens the scope of this answer.

I would suggest wrapping their code (except the .ready()) into a function which takes arguments: the select's selector, and the drop down menu's selector:

```
function createHTMLSelect(selectSel, menuSel) {
    // declare this instead
    var select = $(selectSel);

    ...

    // also this
    var dropDown = $('<ul>',{className:menuSel});
}
```

You then call your function for each select you have on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// first select
createHTMLSelect('select.makeFancy', 'dropDown');

// second select
createHTMLSelect('select.makeMoreFancy', 'otherDropDown');

... 

});
```

You will have to have different class names for each select/dropdown menu combination given the way this code was written.

I haven't tested this, so there might be some other tweaks to get it to work.